# init call to subclassed SKSpriteNode not happening

Tags: swift2, init, skscene

In DemoBots os(iTV) when you call:-

```
let scene = sceneMetadata.sceneType.init(fileNamed: sceneMetadata.fileName)!
```

it calls

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
```

in ButtonNode which is a subclass of SKSpriteNode.

The call for scene invokes SKScene class which is a a subset of SKNode which conforms to NSCoding.

But when I try to implement this in my project I call `let scene =` etc but there is no call to `init?(coder`

I made a test programme which worked and checked my project conformed to this and the DemoBots but I cant see why it is not working!

P.S. The test program did not work at first and then it did, but I don't know what changed.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  I've edited your code (four spaces at the front of the line to automatically format it) so that it's easier to read.  Unfortunately, I don't know the programming language well enough to tag this with an appropriate tag.  You really should [edit] your post to tag it with the appropriate language.